# Fully Decentralized Dapp

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, abi, ipfs, decentralization

How can I build a fully decentralized dapp where the frontend code (.html,.css,.js) and ABI files (build/contracts/json) are stored in ipfs and contracts on test-network. But I am unable to do so because I am not getting the ABI after deploying in rinkeby etc. through Remix or truffle. Please guide me through the whole process stepwise.

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you have an specific issue with Remix or Truffle you should ask that instead. For example Remix in the "compile" tab has an "ABI" button that will copy your contract abi to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Connect with rinkeby network by including this in truffle-config.js

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic ="<your account mnemoic>";
var INFURA_API_KEY = "<your api key>";
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          mnemonic,
          "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + INFURA_API_KEY
        ),
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 3000000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000
    }
  }
};
```

Connect the metamask by including this:

```
web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<your api key>");
```

run this command from console

```
truffle migrate -f 2 --network rinkeby
```

And include the frontend files and the contracts ABI generated on IPFS.